# C# Settings with Flag Enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I've enums as flags like:

```
[Flags]
public enum ResultValues
{
    None = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Yellow = 2,
    Green = 4,
    Other = 8
};
```

In my code I can OR-connect these flags and all works fine.

Now I store variables of this enum type in the settings.
If I add a setting entry, I can set as type the enum from above and select/set one (!) of the values as default (e.g. Green).

```
<Setting Name="FilterResult" Type="MyNamespace.ResultValues" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">Green</Value>
</Setting>
```

But how can I store a combination of values as default - as I can do this in code with

```
ResultValues.Red | ResultValues.Yellow | ResultValues.Green | ResultValues.Other
```

Comment: What kind of settings are these (ie what kind of app is this for) and how are you setting the value?

Comment: You can store setting as an integer. Red + Yellow = 3. Then you can parse 3 to Red | Yellow with a function.

Comment: @Seabizkit When dealing with bit-wise flags 0 always means none as it's the state will all bits set to 0.  Otherwise a value of 3 would mean None and Red, which makes no sense.

Comment: @juharr yes sorry you are very correct. ill delete... but wouldn't he still store 15

Comment: @Seabizkit That is the value for all 4 combined, which would be fine for storing in a DB, but in a xml file you usually want something more readable like the suggested comma separated names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can store the values just by separating them with a comma:

```
<Value Profile="(Default)">Green, Other</Value>
```

The built-in parser will convert such a string to the correct "combined" enum value:

```
ResultValues.Green | ResultValues.Other
```

Answer (score 5):

Comma separated:

```
Flags f = Enum.Parse<Flags>("Red,Yellow,Green");
```